# Google API to retrieve information about an OAuth app

Tags: google-api, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace

How can I programmatically retrieve information about an OAuth client given its appId (xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com). I am interested in retrieving Google API scopes the app is requesting (e.g.: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email) along with marketplace ratings and user coun t (if applicable).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEO7b.png)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can only access those stats if you own the app/add-on. Assuming that you're working on a GSute add-on, if you deploy the app via GSuite Marketplace you'll have to explicitly specify the scopes your app requires and you can check those scopes from your Google Console. I believe that there is also a dashboard available to the app developer (probable from Google Console) with analytic data related to performance.

Comment: Thanks for your response Dimu ! May be I should clarify, please look at the following screenshot, I would like to retrieve the scopes highlighted in the screenshot programmatically. I have seen a third party API that contains this information (among a number of other things) so I am guessing there is a Google API that this third party solution calls.    [Screenshot][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEO7b.png